# Возможно ли передать виртуальное нажатие клавиш в конкретную программу?

Tags: python-3.x, windows, winapi, pyautogui, ctypes

Доброго веремени суток!

Подскажите, могу ли я передать виртуальное нажатие клавиш в конкретную программу? Например, таким образом: `ctypes.windll.user32.keybd_event(key_code, 0, KEYEVENTF_KEYDOWN, 0)` в поле для текста?

И возможно ли передать данные в конкретную программу (например получив ее таким `ctypes.windll.user32.GetForegroundWindow()` или иным способом)?

Заранее благодарю!

Comment: уточните. в неактивное/свёрнутое окно ?

Comment: Окно активное. Только почемуто с даной програмой keybd_event не работает. Для теста в открытый блокнот и консоль пишет. Может ли быть какаято защита?

Comment: может. попробуйте вот эту штуку https://pypi.org/project/PyDirectInput/

Comment: Выражаю Вам максимальную благодарность! Работет!